# Attempting to create a cookie and redirect user to home page, however redirect not happening

Tags: php

I have two pages; a home page and a login page. When a user first tries to navigate to my home page, I check whether there is a cookie that indicates that the user has been authenticated, if they have not been authenticated, I redirect them to a login page.

If the login is authenticated by a third party API I am using for authentication, I create a token with the authentication token received (I don't have to worry about security pertaining to what I store in the cookie). I then redirect the user back to the home page.

The problem is, with the last step, I am creating a cookie and attempting to redirect the user, however, I am redirected back to the login form as if there is no cookie

This is the code in the home page checking for a valid cookie:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['authToken'])){
    header ("location: /login.php");
  }
?>
```

This is where I create the cookie and call this function upon successful authentication:

```
function createCookie($token){
    $cookie_name = 'authToken';
    $cookie_value = $token;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400*30), "/");
    header("Location: /index");
}
...
function makePostRequest($baseURL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = http_build_query($_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
        $json = json_decode($response, true);
        createCookie($json);
        return print_r($json);
    }
}
```

Any pointers as to what I might be doing wrong

Comment: You have a typo where you're setting `$cooke_value` instead of `$cookie_value`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto Thanks, I'm still getting the same issue